# UFT Image used as button

Tags: vbscript, error-handling, qtp

I am trying to run the below code, but it throws and error when executing the last line of code.

```
Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").WebEdit("name:=age").Set 26
Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").WebEdit("name:=retirementage").Set 70
Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").WebEdit("name:=lifeexpectancy").Set 80
Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").WebEdit("name:=income").Set 50000
Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").WebEdit("name:=incomeincrease").Set 3
Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").WebEdit("name:=balance").Set 150000
Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").WebEdit("name:=contribution").Set 10
Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").WebEdit("name:=inflation").Set 5

Browser("name:=401K Calculator").Page("title:=401K Calculator").Image("file name:=calculate.png","index=0").Click
```

When I use Object spy on the button (image), it shows its name as"image" instead Button.

I am using the script on **http://www.calculator.net/401k-calculator.html** website.

Here is the error:
"Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Browser(...).Page(...).Image'"

What should I change in order to get it to work?

Answer (score 3):

The description you gave for the calculate button is:

```
"file name:=calculate.png","index=0"
```

The first part is fine but in the `index` part you forgot the `:` that tells UFT you're using descriptive programming. It should be:

```
"file name:=calculate.png","index:=0"
' You forgot this                ^
```

Comment: Oops! Yes, that solved the problem. Thanks. The error should have been comprehensive to the users. :)